# Разбить строку с пробелами

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть переменная:

```
 $slova = "раз два      три         четыре пять";
```

Я хочу разбить ее на отдельные слова, но при этом не учитывать пробелы:

```
  $arr = explode("\n", $slova);
   foreach ($arr as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    echo $word."<br />";
   }
```

Но в таком случае пробелы учитывает. Как быть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$slova = "раз два      три         четыре пять";
$data   = preg_split('/\s+/', $slova);
```

Answer (score 3):

можно заюзать регулярку, вместо explode:

```
<?php
$slova = "раз два      три         четыре пять";
$arr = preg_split("/( )+/", $slova);
foreach ($arr as $word) {
    echo $word."<br />";
}
```

Comment: А зачем в этом варианте trim ? `$word` же не может содержать проблелов?

Comment: да, trim не нужен. быстрый копи-паст ^_^ убрал